# GUI update in cycle

Tags: java, user-interface

I set a random number and I want the label to display numbers from 0 to a random number in steps of 0.01, but the problem is that the display is updated only after the cycle is completed.

When the user clicks the button, the program freezes and then displays the final value. I would like it to gradually increase the value, while displaying the screen. 0 -> 0.01-> 0.02 and so on.

Tried to use cycle for,while. I am thinking of creating an array.

```
public class Crash extends JFrame {
private JTextField textBet;
private JLabel lblBalance;
private JButton btnStart;
private double theNumber;
private static double num[];
private String msg="";
private JLabel lblMakeABet;
private int Balance=10000,bet=0;
private double i;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

public void newGame() {
    theNumber = Math.round((Math.random() * 10) * 100.0) / 100.0;
    lblBalance.setText("Balance: "+Balance);
}
public Crash() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    lblBalance = new JLabel("Balance:");
    lblBalance.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblBalance.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    lblBalance.setBounds(0, 30, 486, 30);
    getContentPane().add(lblBalance);

    lblMakeABet = new JLabel("Make a bet and press start.");
    lblMakeABet.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblMakeABet.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    lblMakeABet.setBounds(0, 90, 476, 23);
    getContentPane().add(lblMakeABet);

    JLabel lblPlaceABet = new JLabel("Place a bet :");
    lblPlaceABet.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    lblPlaceABet.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
    lblPlaceABet.setBounds(86, 143, 150, 30);
    getContentPane().add(lblPlaceABet);

    textBet = new JTextField();
    textBet.setBounds(246, 149, 96, 23);
    getContentPane().add(textBet);
    textBet.setColumns(10);

    btnStart = new JButton("Start");
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            try {    
                for ( i = 0 ; i <theNumber ; i+=0.01){
                    msg=df.format(i);
                    lblMakeABet.setText(msg);
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    btnStart.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    btnStart.setBounds(180, 203, 104, 30);
    getContentPane().add(btnStart);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Crash theGame = new Crash();
    theGame.newGame();
    theGame.setSize(new Dimension(450,300));
    theGame.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

mistake here

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            try {    
                for ( i = 0 ; i <theNumber ; i+=0.01){
                    msg=df.format(i);
                    lblMakeABet.setText(msg);
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```